# Java and IP - Subnet parsing

Tags: java, networking, subnet

Is there an easy way in java to get the range of an IP from the format of

175.25.0.0/16

to somewhat like 
175.25.0.0-175.25.255.255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> public String getHostAddressRange(String netmaskNumeric) {
>
> ```
>     int numberOfBits;
>     for (numberOfBits = 0; numberOfBits < 32; numberOfBits++) {
>
>         if ((netmaskNumeric << numberOfBits) == 0)
>             break;
>     }
>     Integer numberOfIPs = 0;
>     for (int n = 0; n < (32 - numberOfBits); n++) {
>
>         numberOfIPs = numberOfIPs << 1;
>         numberOfIPs = numberOfIPs | 0x01;
>
>     }
>
>     Integer baseIP = baseIPnumeric & netmaskNumeric;
>     String firstIP = convertNumericIpToSymbolic(baseIP + 1);
>     String lastIP = convertNumericIpToSymbolic(baseIP + numberOfIPs - 1);
>     return firstIP + " - " + lastIP;
> }
> ```